# Ubuntu 20.04 Network Interface Does Not Initialize At Boot

Tags: networking

Just moved my server to 20.04.  So far so good but I'm seeing an issue where the network interface does not come up at boot --  sometimes. Seems random when it fails, but issuing an ifup after logging in will always bring the network up.  I was running 18.04 before and never had this issue.  The ethernet controller is a "Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection" built into the Intel motherboard.

Any tips on how I can diagnose / fix this would be great.